# Functional Testing - How do you track your test cases?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-strategy

So I'm the sole-developer maintaining a software project owned by a non-profit. Being the sole CS guy on the project, I'm finding myself wearing many different hats. One of those is of your typical software developer in-test.

We've been using Github as our issue tracking system, with a fair bit of success. It's a good tool for a project of this size (~25k lines of code, medium size enterprise application).

However, we're still using excel/google docs to track test cases. Spreadsheets here, are not a great tool for measuring test coverage across multiple runs of the test plan. If you're reading this, you probably know that.

I'd like to move us to test tracking software, such that we can better keep track of our test cases. As a non-profit org, the cash we have for testing is limited, and I'd like to make sure we maximize our bang for buck when we do actually spend resources on testing. Further to that, we actually can't afford commercial testing software services like DevTest or qTest.

We looked at Testopia, but it's horribly out of date, and has not been maintained over the years. Other open source solutions seem to have suffered the same fate.

What cheap/free test tracking options are out there?

Comment: I'm still on the hunt for a good tool, spreadsheets are the most cost-effective solution in my opinion especially if you use a slightly customized spreadsheet with some automation (macros or VB code)

Comment: How about using CI software? Is that an option? Kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: CI? Case Integration?

Comment: CI = Continuous Integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When was the last time you looked at Testopia?  They claim their unreleased 3.0 should be basically working..  Also, have you looked at Nitrate?  Claims to be easy to use (ha ha!) and says its intent was to pick up where Testopia left off.

But if I were you I'd take a close look at Kiwi http://kiwitcms.org/ which claims integration with GitHub.. Looks much more modern in many ways.

Comment: Kiwi looks promising, but I'm reluctant to give it access to code in private repositories. That's more a complaint about Github's permission system though.

Comment: We installed the 2.4 version of Testopia. I was poking around the github repo, and it looked like the last commit was in 2017. I'm not optimistic about it.

Comment: And how about kiwi?

Comment: I actually landed on Kiwi. It's good (enough). The UI is a little clunky, but it gets the job done. Definitely a case of you get what you pay for, but good enough is all I ask for in this case.

Comment: Great!  Clunky is not ideal, but it's better than buggy :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check [SquashTM](https://www.squashtest.org/en/decouvrir-squash-tm/contenu-statique/outils-et-fonctionnalites/squash-tm-test-management-en). The latest release was at June'18. As a minus - it is not integrated with GitHub bugtracker, so you would probably have some inconvenience there.

It also probably makes sense to take a look at [this solution](https://github.com/marketplace/testquality). It is free for github public repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [TestRail](https://www.gurock.com/testrail). Used in the past with great success - integrates with github, automation, etc. Overall a nice front end for managing testcases.

Comment: I use and like testrail just fine.  But at work.  Because at $3000+/year, it's not suitable for Steve's nonprofit requirements.

Comment: Point taken - however, depending on the number of users required, it may be within budget.  It seems he may even be the only user, so at $30/month or $360 annually, it may be an viable option.

Comment: I don't know any rich, worldwide nonprofit that'd spend that much just for testing if there was another solution..

Comment: Steve didn't mention worldwide. So, lets consider YMCA. $760 mil on general+management expenses according to Forbes. So, $360 is not significant. My point: you or I don't know enough about the nonprofit requirements (he said cheap, not necessarily free) so calling testrail "not suitable" based on a subjective requirement ("cheap") is misleading.